# Why are some words like "copy" and "insert" coloured green in Code Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I just installed Code Blocks on Linux Mint and loaded some C++ files from an old Visual Studio project.  I noticed that Code Blocks colours some of my function names such as "copy" and "insert" in green, why is that?

Comment: This thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467369/does-codeblocks-reserve-names-other-than-c-keywords talks about "user keywords" which are highlighted in green.

Comment: Likely because it knows about standard functions `std::copy` and `std::container::insert`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't want to use the std library, except maybe for cout and then I just place the "std::" infront.

Comment: Since when was naming functions not a programming related topic?

Comment: @tyebillion This is not about function naming but rather about one editor/IDEs choice of syntax highlighting.  Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 4):

That's just syntax highlighting at work. Every IDE or editor does it its own way (or not at all). Most allow you to customize what gets coloured and in what colour etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off highlighting of STL names in Settings | Editor

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the keywords?