# Why are some keywords colored green in CodeBlocks IDE(C++)?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

[image]

Some keywords are colored green automatically. What do those words mean? Are those keywords reserved for C++? Can I use those words as program variables?

Comment: You can go to the menu `Settings -> Editor -> Syntax highlighting` to see your current syntax highlighting scheme.

Comment: Those are STL code highlights. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340740)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof` is an operator. You can't use it as an identifier.

`size` is a function in `std::`, and also a member of many classes in `std::`. You **should** use it as an identifier, if you are writing a [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) type. It's fine to use it as an identifier elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is a keyword. `size` is not.

For a more comprehensive list have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

Comment: This does not completely answer the question. The green words are STL-related ones.

Comment: @AndréCaceres It answers part of the question, namely *Are those keywords reserved for C++?*. Since I'm not familiar with CodeBlocks I just contributed the information I knew. If you can complement or improve on the answer please do, but if you downvote with the reasoning that my answer could be better, you should probably adjust your voting habits.